# prority queue comparison and update

Tags: python-3.x, priority-queue

A possible solution is to mark the entry as removed and add a new entry with the revised priority. The documentation provides an example implementation:

I am reading about priority queues in python 3 documentation at following link

https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html

Here in implementation details

Priority Queue Implementation Notes

A priority queue is common use for a heap, and it presents several implementation challenges:

> •Sort stability: how do you get two tasks with equal priorities to be
>   returned in the order they were originally added? •Tuple comparison
>   breaks for (priority, task) pairs if the priorities are equal and the
>   tasks do not have a default comparison order. •If the priority of a
>   task changes, how do you move it to a new position in the heap? •Or if
>   a pending task needs to be deleted, how do you find it and remove it
>   from the queue?

I am not able to understand below. Particularly "what does if tasks do not have a default comparison order" Request to elaborate with example

•Tuple comparison breaks for (priority, task) pairs if the priorities are equal and the tasks do not have a default comparison order

Thanks for your time and help